# Separate array elements with *ngFor

Tags: angular, random, ngfor

I'm working on an assignment where I have to, using Angular, generate random 12 numbers and put them in a list (one number per one list element).

Right now I'm getting result in which every od 12 list items looks the same i.e.

- 1674,4769,3549,7093,6751,6277,2980,427,2358,257,5558,8331

I can't find a solution on how to put each of the random digits in a separate bullet.

HTML:

```
<button (click)="generateNumbers()">Wygeneruj liczby</button>
<li *ngFor="let number of randomNumbers">
  {{ randomNumbers }}
</li>
```

component.ts

```
public randomNumbers: number[];

  generateNumbers(){
    let array: number[] = [];
    while (array.length <12 ) {
      array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 8719));
    }
    this.randomNumbers = array;
  }
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any advice! :)

Comment: <li *ngFor="let number of randomNumbers">
  {{ number }}
</li>

Comment: The variable holding the current item of the list is `number`. Replace `{{ randomNumbers }}` with `{{ number }}`.

Comment: @Michael D - thank you very much, it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do

```html
<div>
  <button (click)="generateNumbers()">Wygeneruj liczby</button>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let number of randomNumbers">
      {{ number }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-currying-xpprk?file=/src/app/app.component.html:0-235)